# How to stop vim colorscheme using wrong colours for visible tab characters

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

In my vim setup, I have invisible char show up with `set list`. I am using solarized dark theme, but changing theme I still get the same problem and sometimes a lot worse!
The tab characters are showing up a different colour from the background.

[image: Coloured tabs]

How do I stop this behaviour as the effect is overpowering when it should be subtle!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:help 'listchars'` explains:

```
The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and
"precedes".  "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "space", "tab" and "trail".
|hl-NonText| |hl-SpecialKey|
```

So, what's annoying you is the background color of the `SpecialKey` highlight group. (Unless you use some special indent-highlight plugin, but you would have told us, right?)

To fix this, just redefine the highlight group, after a `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`. For example, clear the background color:

```
:highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
```